# Deserializing XML File & storing the type (Crashing)

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having a problem which I've been stuck on for days now. I'm deserializing an XML from another developer into a class and I keep getting the exception "InvalidOperationException: The specified type was not recognized: name='string', namespace='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', at .".

This triggers at 'Tag' in the code below in 'DevListViewItem'. If I make 'Tag' as a string, it gets the text fine, but this means I can't store the type for serialization back later.

Any help is truly appreciated.

An example of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfDevListViewItem xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <DevListViewItem>
    <Index>0</Index>
    <Key>0</Key>
    <Tag xsi:type="xsd:string">[Category] = 0 And [CanOpen] = False</Tag>
    <Group />
    <Text>Can Open?</Text>
    <Subitem1>[Category] = 0 And [CanOpen] = False</Subitem1>
    <Subitem1Integer>0</Subitem1Integer>
    <Subitem2Integer>0</Subitem2Integer>
    <Subitem3Integer>0</Subitem3Integer>
    <ExtraData />
    <IsRead>true</IsRead>
    <Iconindex>0</Iconindex>
    <Sort />
    <Condition>false</Condition>
    <Checked>false</Checked>
    <HasInfoButton>false</HasInfoButton>
    <HasExecuteButton>false</HasExecuteButton>
    <IsBold>false</IsBold>
  </DevListViewItem>
</ArrayOfDevListViewItem>
```

My C# Code:

```
   public class FilterXMLSchema
    {
        public class Tag
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
            public string Type { get; set; }

            [XmlText]
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }

        public class DevListViewItem
        {

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Index")]
            public int Index { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Key")]
            public string Key { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tag")]
            public Tag Tag { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Group")]
            public object Group { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Text")]
            public string Text { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Subitem1")]
            public string Subitem1 { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Subitem1Integer")]
            public int Subitem1Integer { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Subitem2Integer")]
            public int Subitem2Integer { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Subitem3Integer")]
            public int Subitem3Integer { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ExtraData")]
            public object ExtraData { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsRead")]
            public bool IsRead { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Iconindex")]
            public int Iconindex { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sort")]
            public object Sort { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Condition")]
            public bool Condition { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Checked")]
            public bool Checked { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "HasInfoButton")]
            public bool HasInfoButton { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "HasExecuteButton")]
            public bool HasExecuteButton { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsBold")]
            public bool IsBold { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("{0}", Text);
            }
        }

        public class ArrayOfDevListViewItem
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "DevListViewItem", Namespace = "")]
            public List<DevListViewItem> DevListViewItem = new();

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
            public string Xsi;

            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
            public string Xsd;

            [XmlText]
            public string Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `public object Tag { get; set; }` because `xsi:type="xsd:string"` is just a way of storing what the type name is if it doesn't match the actual property type

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you! If you reply as an answer rather than a comment I'll mark it as such!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `Tag` property to

```
public object Tag { get; set; }
```

Because `xsi:type="xsd:string"` is just a way of storing what the type name is if it doesn't match the actual property type. So you need to use `object` so that it will use that to work out the real type.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify your class to handle the xsi:type attribute on the Tag element. You can create separate class for the Tag element that can handle the xsi:type attribute.

For that I removed the tag property first and replaced it with the name of my new class. Call is TagWrapper.

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Tag")]
public TagWrapper TagWrapper { get; set; }
```

Then created the new class within DevListViewItem.

```
public class TagWrapper
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator string(TagWrapper tagWrapper)
    {
        return tagWrapper.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator TagWrapper(string value)
    {
        return new TagWrapper { Value = value };
    }
}
```

The Value property will hold the text of tag and type the value of xsi:type